# How do I omit certain files from the `git status` report?

Tags: git

I'm using git and developing in Python (although this is obviously relevant to any other data managed with git). How do I tell git I don't want to see all the `.pyc` files from python in `git status`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to the file `.gitignore` the following line:

```
*.pyc
```

See [gitignore(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).